# How to copy text from one document to another with same formatting?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this code to copy some text from one document to a new one.

```
For Each rng In docSource.SpellingErrors
   docNew.Range.InsertAfter rng.text & vbCr
Next
```

Bus this is not copying the source format.

I'm trying with the following line but I get error

> Expected function or variable

```
docNew.Range.InsertAfter rng.PasteAndFormat(wdPasteDefault) & vbCr
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Below some test text with errors.

```
When you create a Microsoft Word document for other people to read , it's important to spot and correct any speling mistakes

or gramatical errors you've made. You can let Word's spelling and grammmar

checkers suggest corrections automaticaly while you working , or you can check the spelling and gramar in the the file all 

at once when you're finishes writing your document . Microsoft Word 2010 come with some dictionary of standardd grammar and spellings, but they are not comprehensive.
```

Comment: `& vbCr` --> try without that / and to paste You need to copy, not insert

Comment: Still not working removing `& vbCr`

Comment: `Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. In Word, much of the formatting is in the paragraph. Therefore the formatting of the destination paragraph will have a major impact on how anything you paste into it will be displayed. So, what are the formats that you wish to see in `DocNew`?

Comment: @0m3r Thanks for your answer. I added to your suggestion `rng.copy` and almost work, but when the macro is running I see that is pasting each text in the same position and previous text disappears. I´ve added `VbCr` but the same happens. How to print each text one line after the previous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer content from one Word document to another it's usually best to use `Range.FormattedText` rather than the Clipboard.

So something like this

```
Set docNewRange = docNew.Content
For Each rng In docSource.SpellingErrors
   docNewRange.FormattedText = rng.FormattedText 
   docNewRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
   docNewRange.InsertAfter vbCr
   docNewRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

For example You wish a range from oDoc1 copy to oDoc2. It's my solution:

```
rngPara1st = oDoc1.Range( -set desired range- )
oDoc2 = oWord.Documents.Add
oDoc2.Activate()
rngPara2nd = oDoc2.Range
rngPara2nd.FormattedText = rngPara1st.FormattedText
```